# Does a mutual fund's expense ratio include the management fee?

Tags: mutual-funds

Fidelity's information about their Spartan International Index Fund - Investor Class (FSIIX) has the following information about expenses and fees:

[image: Expenses & Fees]

Is the 0.17% management fee included in the 0.20% expense ratio, or is it in addition to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The expense ratio is the annual fee that all funds or ETFs charge their shareholders. It expresses the percentage of assets deducted each fiscal year for fund expenses, including 12b-1 fees, management fees, administrative fees, operating costs, and all other asset-based costs incurred by the fund.

[Expense Ratio(Morningstar)](http://www.morningstar.com/InvGlossary/expense_ratio.aspx)

> Costs associated with mutual funds but not included in operating expenses are loads and redemption fees, which, if they apply, are paid directly by fund investors.

[Expense Ratio(Investopedia)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/expenseratio.asp)